# List nodes from a taxonomy based on a field

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, entities, blocks

I'm looking for the most "Drupal" way to create either a view/block (not sure about either) that contains a list with the top level items being the parent taxonomies from a certain vocabulary (4 parents in total), and then nested under each taxonomy, the first 5 products that have a certain field on them set to true.

Essentially a "featured products"-esque block that will have 4 tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to do the following:

1) **Create a view for products**

- Install Views Field View module
- http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view Create a view for 4
  products. Make sure it has contextual filter for term id set.
- Save it

2) **Create a taxonomy view**

- Create taxonomy view, set display as block, so you could output it in
  a block
- Add 'taxonomy term parent' filter and make it equal to 0. This way you'll select only parent terms
- Select Views Field View in Fields and set it to output a view for products
- Save

So now you should have a block which outputs parent taxonomy terms and under each term you have a list of products.

Let me know how it works.

Comment: I have made some progress, I have the view within a view, but all the sub-products for each taxonomy are the same..